# What is the difference between a singleton and a module that instantiates an instance?

Tags: node.js, singleton

I want to add a metrics class to my code. What is the difference between

```
class MyMetrics {
  constructor () {
    if (!Singleton.instance) {
      Singleton.instance = new Metrics()
    }
    return Singleton.instance
  }
}

const metrics = new MyMetrics()
```

and

```
export const metrics = new Metrics()
```

Wouldn't each module that imported `metrics` be using the same Metrics instance?

Are they functionally the same for my usage? Which would be recommended?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help] *"Which would be recommended?"* That's opinion-based, so it's mostly off topic here. More: [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Wouldn't each module that imported `metrics` be using the same Metrics instance?

Yes, they would.

> Are they functionally the same for my usage?

As long as A) you aren't creating other instances within the module and B) you aren't exporting `Metrics`, yes, almost. But one thing to remember is that any code that has access to your `metrics` import has access to your `Metrics` constructor, indirectly via the `constructor` property `metrics` inherits from `Metrics.prototype`:

```
import { metrics } from "./your-module.js";
const newMetrics = new metrics.constructor();
```

You might think that with the singleton, you've avoided that, but that's easily defeated as `instance` is public:

```
import { metrics } from "./your-module.js";
const Metrics = metrics.constructor;
Metrics.instance = null;
const newMetrics = new Metrics();
```

So you might want to make it private (either using a static private property, or just using `metrics` itself to check if you've created it).

> Which would be recommended?

That's a matter of opinion. But you might not even need a class at all. You could:

- Just make an object directly without a constructor function.
- Export functions and close over module-private variables.

For instance, consider this (fairly silly) class:

```
// stuff.js
class Stuff {
    #items = new Map();
    constructor() {
        // ...pretend there's singleton logic here...
    }
    put(key, value) {
        this.#items.set(key, value);
    }
    get(key) {
        return this.#items.get(key);
    }
}
export const stuff = new Stuff();
```

The way you use that is:

```
import { stuff } from "./stuff.js";

stuff.put("this", "that");
stuff.get("this"); // "that"
```

You could just get rid of the class entirely:

```
// stuff.js
const items = new Map();
export const stuff = {
    put(key, value) {
        items.set(key, value);
    },
    get(key) {
        return items.get(key);
    }
};
```

Usage would be the same:

```
import { stuff } from "./stuff.js";

stuff.put("this", "that");
stuff.get("this"); // "that"
```

Or you could just export `put` and `get`:

```
// stuff.js
const items = new Map();
export const put = (key, value) => {
    items.set(key, value);
};
export const get = (key) => items.get(key);
```

Then usage is:

```
import { get, put } from "./stuff.js";

put("this", "that");
get("this"); // "that"
```

Or if those names may conflict with other things:

```
import { get as getStuff, put as putStuff } from "./stuff.js";

putStuff("this", "that");
getStuff("this"); // "that"
```

So you have lots of options to choose from. Constructor functions (including ones created with `class` syntax) are useful if you need to construct multiple objects with shared characteristics, but if you aren't doing that (and you aren't with a singleton), just writing the object directly or (with modules) exporting the things it can do directly may be good options for you.